# Vue @click event not working for showing modal

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a laravel SPA and I'm using Vue.js as a front end. I encountered this error and I dont know how to solve this because I think there was nothing wrong with my code. All the `@click` function in my component works except for the `editModal` function in my edit button for my table. Can someone help me?

Users.vue

```
<button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew">
 <table class="table table-hover">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Registered</th>
              <th>Modify</th>
            </tr>

            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <td>{{user.id}}</td>
              <td>{{user.name}}</td>
              <td>{{user.email}}</td>
              <td>{{user.type| upText}}</td>
              <td>{{user.created_at| myDate}}</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash text-red"></i>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

//Modal
<div class="modal fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...some modal code



<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: {},
      form: new Form({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: "",
        bio: "",
        photo: ""
      })
    };
  },

  methods: {

    editModal(user){
         this.form.reset();
         $('#addNew').modal('show');
    },
      newModal(){
          this.form.reset();
          $('#addNew').modal('show');
    },

    loadUsers() {
      axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data.data));
    },
    createUser() {
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form.post("api/user")

      .then(() => {
        $("#addNew").modal("hide");
        $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
        toast.fire({
          type: "success",
          title: "User Created!",
          position: "top-end"
        });
     Fire.$emit("AfterCreate")
      });
      this.$Progress.finish();
    },
    deleteUser(id) {
      swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
      }).then(result => {

          //send delete request
           if (result.value) {
          this.form.delete('api/user/' +id)
            .then(()=>{

                swal.fire("Deleted!", "", "success");
                 Fire.$emit("AfterCreate")

            })
            .catch(()=>{
                swal.fire("Something went wrong.", "", "warning");
            });
           }
      });

    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
    this.loadUsers();
    Fire.$on("AfterCreate",()=> {
      this.loadUsers();
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please add your implementation at jsfiddle

Comment: i dont know how to add code at jsfiddle sir. Im just new in stackoverflow

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: How is `editModal` not working? Is the model not showing at all or is it something else?

Comment: Yes sir, the modal for `editModal` is not showing. But when I try to add a new user, the modal shows.

Comment: The styles wont load in jsfiddle sir and I find it hard to use for now. Im sorry. @EmīlsGulbis

Comment: Any errors in your development console?

Comment: No errors were found in my console sir @Jerodev

Comment: All the functions worked except for this `editModal` . I can add and delete but when I click edit button from my table, the modal wont show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I just played with my code and changed the code from

`<a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">`

to

`<a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew" @click="editModal(user)">`

.
 Do you think it is the good solution? yes or no? please let me know so that i can learn

Answer (score 2):

I made working example for you

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  
  created() {
   this.fetchUsers()
  },
  
  methods: {
   fetchUsers() {
   axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
       .then(response => this.users = response.data)
    },
    
    newModal() {
   $('#addNew').modal('show');
    },
    
    editModal(user) {
     $('#addNew').modal('show');
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<div id="app">
  <button class="btn btn-success" @click="newModal"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNew">Add new</button>
  <table class="table table-hover">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>

     <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
       <td>{{user.id}}</td>
       <td>{{user.name}}</td>
       <td>{{user.email}}</td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" @click="editModal(user)">
           Edit
         </a>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="addNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        Here I'm
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used `$('#addNew').modal('show');`  in my code but still not working. Any idea?

Comment: It runs here but when i implement it in my code its not working. How could i refresh my js files or something like that? I think thats what i need